# SharePoint 2013 Apps to Apps Communication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am having the requirement that I have two apps[Client App Parts]. The user is trying to drag some items from App1 to App2, App2 do some action. This functionality is available in SP 2013. I have added two SP 2013 Document library apps. But SP 2013 not allowed to drag item from App1 to App2, but it is allowed to drag the item from App1 to App2[Which is listed in Recent Items]. I'm aware that App-2-App communication is not possible in SP 2013. Is it anyway to implement this scenario in SP 2013?